# Are the dates of answers assuming we're still in 2009?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, dates

For the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999313/iphone-app-signing-a-valid-signing-identity-matching-this-profile-could-not-be-f) (but on all answers I'd guess) the dates say something like "Aug 12 at 19:04". Is this deliberate or a bug that thinks it's 2009 still?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's the desired behavior as "Aug 12" unambiguously refers to "Aug 12, 2009". Year is needed only for dates more than 11 month old.

I looked up an old answer of mine from January 2009 to see the timestamp. It explicitly mentions "'09" which means StackOverflow engine smartly formats timestamps based on the current date.
[How to store a list in a db column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444251/how-to-store-a-list-in-a-db-column/444268#444268)

Comment: Not sure I agree with it adding any value as last year is last year, but if it's by design then ok

Answer (score 2):

If you hover over the date, it gives you the complete Date/Time stamp.

If there's no year, you can assume they the current or former year, as long as another year hasn't elapsed.